# Resolve IP address from MAC address

Tags: networking

I am working in a network with subnet mask 255.255.0.0 (i.e 65534 hosts). The network has IP assignment scheme with DHCP server. In case of system restart or lease time completion, the system's IP is renewed. How would I be able to get the IP address of a system whose MAC address is available to me? Because in case of such large network, it would be difficult to ping each host and then read its MAC from arp cache.

I have also tried to use 'arping' utility but its also giving me TIMEOUT even though the system is pingable using IP address. This might be occurring because the arping utility sends broadcast ICMP request and most of the systems in my network do not reply to broadcast pings.

Comment: In other word, you want to probe the database containing (IP,mac) association ? It depends mostly on the software giving  IPs, I know no standard ways to do it remotely.

Comment: If i had access to the DHCP server, then IP could have been found using the lease table.. But in this case, my machine is also a computer from same network with no access to DHCP server :(

Comment: If you can't get a copy of the lease table, and they don't respond to broadcast ping, I don't think there's any solution other than scanning the entire IP range. There are tools like `nmap` that automate this.